# Why does $\dim M > \dim N \implies$ there are no regular points $x \in M$, where $M,N$ are smooth manifolds?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry

Let $f:M \rightarrow N$ be a smooth function between smooth manifolds $M,N$. A regular point is a point $x \in M$ s.t. $d_xf$ is surjective. Why does $\dim M> \dim N$ mean that there are no regular points in $M$?

I attempted to show this by contradiction: assume $x$ is regular,so $d_xf:T_xM \rightarrow T_{f(x)}N$ is a surjection. Thus $\forall y \in T_{f(x)}N,$ $ \exists$ $ v \in T_xM$ s.t. $d_xf(v) = y$. But dim $T_{f(x)}N=\dim N < \dim M = \dim T_xM$. But this is not a contradiction since we can still have a surjection from a higher dimension to one of lower dimension. This seems to show that actually $\dim M< \dim N$ means there are no regular points in $M$.

Where is this argument flawed, and what am I misunderstanding?

Comment: See my edits to this question for proper MathJax usage.$\qquad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you wanted to say $\dim N>\dim M$.
Intuitively the idea is that there is not enough space. But concretely, for a regular point the differential of $f$ must be surjective. Since the dimension of $N$ is bigger that the dimension of $M$ there is no way for a linear map to be surjective between the tangent spaces.

Comment: Yes, indeed my lecturer wrote the inequality the wrong way around and I did not realise...